# Coldfusion, send cfhtmltopdf by email

Tags: coldfusion

Is possible to send a pdf created using cfhtmltopdf in the email? I'm trying to set the cfhtmltopdf in a variable and send by email, but I think it is not possible.

Here is my test cfhtmltopdf:

```
<cfhtmltopdf
  orientation="portrait"  pagetype="A4" margintop="1" marginbottom="1" marginleft="1">
  <html>
  <head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </head>
  </html>
</cfhtmltopdf>
```

Comment: Can't you just specify a destination and then reference that destination in your attachment?

Comment: I;m sorry, what do you mean by set a destination? My code will generates an html (it can change depending on user input). Then, I want to send it by email as PDF

Comment: Have you read the cfhtmltopdf documentation. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhtmltopdf.html You can set a destination parameter which will save the pdf and then use that file as an attachment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add `destination` attribute with the path for creating the file, then use that path for the mail.

```
<cfset filePath = GetTempDirectory() & "emailfile.pdf">
<cfhtmltopdf destination="#filePath#" orientation="portrait"  pagetype="A4" margintop="1" marginbottom="1" marginleft="1" >
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</cfhtmltopdf>
<cfmail to="..." .... >
    <cfmailparam file="#filePath#" disposition="attachment" type="#fileGetMimeType(filePath)#" remove="true">
    <cfmailpart type="html">Content</cfmailpart>
</cfmail>
```